# Combine CSS + jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, background, tabs

This question is quite hard to explain. But I have around 10 seconds of animation on my website that happens from time to time. This works great as long as the user is still on the website.

When the user switches tab before the animation, and enters back in during the animation, it gets messed up. I am combining some jQuery and CSS animations (transform). The CSS animations seem to delay, and only execute once i enter the tab.

The reason why I use CSS animation, is because of the performance. And the reason i use jQuery is because the timing of events (first move right, then left, then down, etc).

What would be the best way to deal with this problem? Is there any way to force a CSS animation to start even when in a background tab?

Help would be MUCH appreciated! Greetings, Fredrik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, is there some way to force start a CSS animation even though the browser tab is not in focus? Because right now, my solution is to perform all animations with jQuery, but it makes the animation more laggy etc :/